# How should "round down" treat negative results in unsigned minifloat implementation?

Tags: ieee-754

I'm working on a [Minifloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat) implementation and am unsure how to treat negative results when rounding down (a.k.a. "round floor" or "round toward -∞") and there's no sign bit.

I.e. in the simplest case, a 0.1.1 minifloat (with values `{0, 1, Infinity, NaN}`), I assume `0 - 1` (or any other negative result for that matter) would evaluate to `0` when rounding up, but if we're using the "round down" rule, should it be `0` or `NaN`?

EDIT: For clarification, in my case I'm primarily interested in just rounding higher-precision numbers to the "most correct" element of the smaller subset. Also, removed "IEEE 754" from title, since this is non-standard.

Comment: IEEE 754 does not have unsigned formats.  The only binary formats are 16, 32, 64, 128, and 256 bits.  So, I guess you can do what you want.

Comment: You can do what you want but IEEE-754 usually words rounding down as giving the result "not higher than the infinitely precise result" or something like that. If you want to follow the words, you have no number representing that, so you should return NaN

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware that this is not a standard format, but I'm trying to intuit what would be the least surprising result.  The "not higher" wording makes it easier to reason about, so I think NaN would be the natural choice here.

Answer (score 1):

When rounding down in an unsigned minifloat implementation, negative results should be treated as the minimum representable value for the minifloat.

Unsigned minifloats can represent numbers between 0 and the maximum representable value, with no sign bit. Therefore, negative numbers cannot be directly represented in an unsigned minifloat.

When rounding down, negative results should be treated as if they were the minimum representable value. This means that any negative result would be rounded down to 0, as that is the smallest value that can be represented in the minifloat.

For example, if the minifloat has a precision of 3 bits and the range is from 0 to 7, rounding down -2 would result in 0.

It's important to note that unsigned minifloats are not designed to represent negative numbers, and this rounding behavior is just a workaround to handle negative results in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking more about what makes the most sense, taking these answers/comments into consideration, and a quick sounding-board chat with ChatGPT, I decided it makes the most sense to hold to the rounding rule definitions as strictly as possible.  So "floor" on all negatives should return `NaN`, while "ceiling" on all negatives should return `+0`.  I think it also makes sense to return `NaN` with "nearest-even" for negative numbers that are more than half ULP below zero—specifically, I'll do the rounding assuming it's signed, and then convert `-0` to `+0`, but any other negative will round to `NaN` as "nearer" than zero.

This seems both least surprising and is also the most versatile.  If a caller would prefer to round negatives to zero, it's easy enough to do `max(0, x)` before rounding, which will replace all negatives with zero first (and preserve `NaN`, at least in JS where this lives).  So the strict choice also ends up being the most flexible, since it's a lot harder to get the `NaN` behavior if the library implementation is permissive.